# How Can I Refresh Data from Database to EF 5.0 DBContext Entities Cache?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 5.0, DBContext Entities,
I obtain data from database through linq queries, something like:

```
from shop in MyEntities.Shops.Include("Equipments") select shop
```

Sometimes I want to refresh part of the cached data, but I don't know how to do this,

I don't want to do it like this :

```
MyEntities = new Entities()
```

,because I only want to refresh part of the cached data;

and I also dont want to Use the Reload() function of each entity,because that 
makes it too slow to accept

So What can I do?

Any word will be appreciated!